# Activities related to services display properly

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to store related activities of services

```html
<form method='post' id='userform' action='arrayvalue.php'>
  <tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='tds'>tds<br> <br>

      <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='One'>Return<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='Two'>Filling<br>
      <br>


      <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='Gst'>Gst<br> <br>
      <td>

        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='One'>Return<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='Two'>Filling<br>
        <br>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table> <input type='submit' name="submit" class='buttons'>
</form>
```

```
<?php if(isset($_POST[submit]) {
    $activity = $_POST['activityvar']; 
    $service = $_POST['servicevar'];

    foreach ($service as $key => $value) {
        echo ($value);
        echo "<br>";

        foreach ($activity as $key => $value) {
            echo ($value);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

MY OUTPUT:

- tds

  - one
  - two
  - one
  - two
- Gst

  - one
  - two
  - one
  - two

Expected Output:

- tds

  - one
  - two
- Gst

  - one
  - two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use One `foreach` loop with index's like :

```
if(isset($_POST[submit]) {
    $activity = $_POST['activityvar']; 
    $service = $_POST['servicevar'];
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($service as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;

        echo $activity[$index]; $index++;
        echo $activity[$index]; $index++;

    }
}
```

**EDIT :** To store the data in your database, use the same concept like :

```
if(isset($_POST[submit]) {
    $activity = $_POST['activityvar']; 
    $service = $_POST['servicevar'];
    $index = 0;
    $nbr_of_related_activities = 2;

    foreach ($service as $key => $value) {
        $servicevalue = $value;

        for ($i=0; $i<$nbr_of_related_activities;$i++) {
            $activityvalue = $activity[$index+$i];

            $query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id) values('$servicevalue','$activityvalue')";
            $insert_row = $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
        }
        $index += $nbr_of_related_activities;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir thankss for help but when i store this values in db then                              
$query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('$value','$activity[$index]')";    $value store services related activity not

Comment: output    tds->1,2   Gst->1,2   display is proper but what about store in database tds and gst store but related activity not store      $query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('$value','$activity[$index]')";

Comment: I think that would be another question isn't it ? we need the informations about this problem, and the related code... so if the my post answers your posted question mark it as correct answer and try to post another one and I'll check it with you too.

Comment: like this we keep the thinks separated for the future readers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: kk sir i will post my question

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the main problem of your post??

Comment: no it help me to display data properly but when i store the value into db then it not works...

Comment: If the data display properly so it could be stored properly if you follow the same concept, and the database storage wasn't a part of this question at all

Comment: $value store services properly, but for activity which variable i use who store checked activity related to checked services

Comment: output:1->1,1->1,2->2,2->2,3->3,3->3

Comment: Make sure you're using `$index++;` add `echo $query;` so we could see the constructed query

Comment: it work fine when i check all checkbox it store proper value but when i check 2nd activity in 1 st service, 1 st activity in 2 nd service and 1st activity in 3 rd service then op:-1->2,1->1,2->1,2->0,3->0,3->0

Comment: Using the concept of array `[]` in your names, make it impossible to know which activities belong to which services when you've unchecked inputs...

Comment: I have only 18 reputation not enough to chat.

Comment: You could vote up, https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up, try it first and I will check the chat privilege reputations

Comment: When you vote up the helpfull posts you encourage people to help you more